# Why am I getting 'No property found for type' error when creating a function besides 'find' functions in JPA+Kotlin?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I'm using jpa+kotlin to develop a muti-thread program
When I'm trying to write functions besides all 'find' functions,I got this error
I don't know why
here's the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fertilizerService' defined in file [F:\GIt\dsdigital\build\classes\kotlin\main\com\example\dsdigital\service\FertilizerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
 Error creating bean with name 'fertilizerRepository' defined in com.example.dsdigital.repository.FertilizerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.dsdigital.model.Fertilizer com.example.dsdigital.repository.FertilizerRepository.saveById(int); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.dsdigital.model.Fertilizer com.example.dsdigital.repository.FertilizerRepository.saveById(int); No property 'saveById' found for type 'Fertilizer'
```

And here's my code:

```
@Entity
//@Table("fertilizer")
class Fertilizer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int? = null
    val serialVersionUID: Long = -7151838606351778881L

    /**设备地址**/
    private val deviceKey: String = "01"

    /**4G地址**/
    var address: String? = null

    /**水泵**/
    var waterPump: Boolean? = null

    /**肥泵**/
    var fatPump: Boolean? = null

    /**A肥搅拌**/
    var fatMixA: Boolean? = null

    /**B肥搅拌**/
    var fatMixB: Boolean? = null

    /**C肥搅拌**/
    var fatMixC: Boolean? = null

    /**A肥**/
    var fatA: Boolean? = null

    /**B肥**/
    var fatB: Boolean? = null

    /**C肥**/
    var fatC: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀一**/
    var valveOne: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀2**/
    var valveTwo: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀3**/
    var valveThree: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀4**/
    var valveFour: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀5**/
    var valveFive: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀6**/
    var valveSix: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀7**/
    var valveSeven: Boolean? = null

    /**区阀8**/
    var valveEight: Boolean? = null

    /**轮灌/定时**/
    var wheelOrTiming: Boolean? = null

    /**手动/自动**/
    var auto: Boolean? = null

    /**远程/本地**/
    var remote: Boolean? = null

    /**轮灌控制**/
    var wheelControl: Boolean? = null

    /**插入时间**/
    var time: LocalDateTime? = null

}
```

```
@Repository

interface FertilizerRepository : JpaRepository<Fertilizer, Int> {

    @Nullable
    fun findByAddress(address: String?): Fertilizer

    //this is the function can't be created
    fun saveById(id:Int):Fertilizer

//    @Nullable
//    fun updateByAddress(address: String?): Fertilizer
}
```

I tried to wirte sql with `@Query`,also this error
And Also I tried write other kinds of functions,only "find" functions could work
I'm not acutal use the function

Comment: What do you want to save with an id? YOu cannot svae just an ID so it will fail. The same for the update by address.